# Using iPad for web development with WordPress

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, proxy, wordpress, ipad

Setup:

- MacBook Pro (Running OS X) with Apache and WordPress install running at http://myhostname
- `myhostname` is mapped to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`
- I can not use URL to access the server, like `192.168.1.4` because the URL changes when I change locations and WordPress is sensitive to that
- I can not use `myhostname` to access the server, because hosts file on iPad can not be changed

How can I access the server from iPad? I tried Squid as a proxy, but that didn't pick up on the hosts file and failed to locate `myhostname`

Answer (score 1):

Setup some sort of dynamic DNS so that you can access your site via a name.